# Failed to send multiple files from JQuery AJAX to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

HTML-

```
<input type="file" id="Photos" multiple />
<button id="SavePhotos">Save</button>
```

JQuery AJAX

```
$('#SavePhotos').click(function () {

  var fd = new FormData();

  fd.append('id', 1);

  var inputs = $('#Photos');
    $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
        var file = v.files[0];
        fd.append("photos", file);
    });


    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + 'BR/TopSheet/SavePhotos?sid=' + sessionId,
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,   
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });

});
```

Action method-

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SavePhotos(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> photos, FormCollection data)
{
        foreach (var file in photos)
        {
           file.SaveAs(path);
        }

        return Json("success");
}
```

But, multiple files are not being sent to action method. It receives only one file. What I am missing here?

Comment: Single element selected at `var inputs = $('#Photos');` ,  single  file sent to server at `v.files[0];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try utilizing `change` event at `input type="file"` to append `File` objects to `FormData` object

html

```
<button id="SavePhotos" disabled="true">Save</button>
```

js

```
// define `fd` , cache `#SavePhotos`
var fd, save = $("#SavePhotos");

$("#Photos").change(function(e) {

  fd = new FormData();

  fd.append("id", 1);
  // append each file to `fd`
  $.each(e.target.files, function (index, file) {
    console.log(file);
    fd.append("photos", file);
  });
  // set `save` `disabled` to `false`
  save.prop("disabled", false)

});

save.click(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + 'BR/TopSheet/SavePhotos?sid=' + sessionId,
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd,
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,   
        beforeSend: function () {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It's working. But would you please explain the issue? I think that will help me better understand the problem.

Comment: @s.k.paul Only single `File` object appended to `FormData` object at `var file = v.files[0];` . Instead of `$.each(inputs` , which iterated single `#Photos` element , iterate all `files` of `#Photos` using `$.each(e.target.files` at `change` event of `#Photos` element . See `console` where `$.each()` logs each individual selected `File` object at `change` event of `input type="file"` . Also , at `js` at Question , `#SavePhotos` could be clicked before any files selected by user